# How to skip lines until I find line of a certain format?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I'm trying to implement a cycle which will read lines off a file until it finds a line with a specific format. Namely, until it finds a line with:

number number character number

and nothing (but spaces or tabs) until the newline. Specifically, the stuff I have to go through until I find such a line will always be the contents of a 'lines.rows' matrix, *but* its data points are not necessarily neatly ordered in 'lines' lines of 'rows' elements. They can have any amount of spaces, tabs or newlines between each element.

However, after lines.rows elements there will always be a line in the format I'm scanning for, after an arbitrary number of spaces, tabs or newlines following the last element of the matrix.

I've been trying for several hours to use fgets and fscanf in different ways to achieve this, but the output is simply not correct. Right now I have this:

```
        for (i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<rows;j++)
        {
            fscanf(in_fp, "%d", &temp);
        }
    }
```

, which is working but takes way too long in large matrices. Aside from this I've tried, for example,

```
        for (i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
            fscanf(in_fp, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL);
    }
```

, which did not work. The idea was to skip to the end of each line and then also read the new line so as to start at the beginning of the following line. However, by the end of this cycle my file was not pointing to the correct line (which would be one with the format specific above - %d %d %c %d). Instead, it was pointing to a 'random' line in the middle of the matrix at hand.

I also tried the same code as above but with an fgets. When I ran an fscanf following a cycle of fgets for all the lines of the matrix, I still did not read the line that should be coming next (with the format specified above).

If you have any input on how to achieve this, or how to make this question more understandable, I would be very thankful.

Comment: "trying for several hours to use fgets and fscanf in different ways to achieve this"+ "to make this question more understandable" -->  post some of those trials.

Comment: @usr2564301 and chux I've tried to add more context to what I've been doing. Thank you very much for the feedback, if it's still not good I'll be happy to edit it again.

Comment: Just for clarity: how large are those matrices, that your basic loop takes too long? A possible bottleneck is then your limited disk speed, and that is very hard to optimize. Out of the blue: is the file still small enough to read in one go and then do the scanning in memory? At the very least that minimizes any further disk access (although in general reading your way is already heavily buffered).

Comment: @usr2564301 they are for example 5000 by 5000. Each entry has a value from 0 to 9. As for disk speed - the program will have to run on the machines at my university, which run slower than my own.

As for your question about the file... I'm not sure how to answer. The file that's giving me trouble has 8500 lines, each line spanning up to 5000 elements on its own, with spaces to boot.